# Load Clockify data to Power BI

Tags: api, powerbi, clockify

I'm having a Power BI report which is based on data from Clockify. So far I had to download the detailed report from clockify in order to be able to see up to date data in Power BI. I would like to get rid of this manual step and directly connect to the data stored in Clockify using the API.

I'm currently loading with following M code:

```
let
    Query1 = let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/",
[Headers=[#"x-api-key"="xxxxxxxxxxx"]])),
messages = Source[messages]
in
Source
```

[This leads to a Record in Power Query which I can then turn into a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRvIZ.png)

But when I expand the table, I only get information about my Clockify Workspace but not the recorded hours. I would like to have all information in the detailed report available directly in Power BI. Hope somebody can help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late responding to this, but thought I would post here what I did. As the OP shows, dealing with APIs is fun. I'm not a fan of that kind of fun, so avoid it when I can.

As a Clockify user (still fairly new I s'pose) I was looking around for a simpler solution, preferably free, but at least at a reasonable cost. If it was cheaper than me doing it (and maintaining it) I was all for it.

What I found was Tugger, they provide linkages to a few different sites, but I was focused on the Clockfy one, a connector they called it ( https://tuggerapp.com/ClockifyIntegration ); I was dubious at first, but with a 30 day free trial, and as I didn't have to enter any credit card details up front, I decided to give it a go.

What I've got is an OData link, a username and password and - well that makes it simple. I imported my data in Power BI pretty soon after signing up.

I also noticed the Power BI report template they provide as part of the monthly fee and that is even easier to use; the same OData link and I have plenty of pages, many of which are hidden - drill throughs in Power BI are great.

I was a little surprised at how good the report looked, but the results were very welcome.

I expect that when my trial finishes, I'll be signing up.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your query and I don't think that the endpoint you're hitting has the information you want. You'll have to search for it in the API documentation.

Anyways, here is the M code for expanding everything in that endpoint, see if it has something useful:

```
let
    Query1 = 
    let
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/workspaces/",
            [Headers=[#"x-api-key"="YOUR-API-KEY"]])),
        #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "name", "hourlyRate", "memberships", "workspaceSettings"}, {"id", "name", "hourlyRate", "memberships", "workspaceSettings"}),
        #"Expanded workspaceSettings" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "workspaceSettings", {"timeRoundingInReports", "onlyAdminsSeeBillableRates", "onlyAdminsCreateProject", "onlyAdminsSeeDashboard", "defaultBillableProjects", "isProjectPublicByDefault", "lockTimeEntries", "round", "projectFavorites", "canSeeTimeSheet", "projectPickerSpecialFilter", "forceProjects", "forceTasks", "forceTags", "forceDescription", "onlyAdminsSeeAllTimeEntries", "onlyAdminsSeePublicProjectsEntries", "trackTimeDownToSecond", "projectGroupingLabel", "adminOnlyPages", "automaticLock", "onlyAdminsCreateTag"}, {"timeRoundingInReports", "onlyAdminsSeeBillableRates", "onlyAdminsCreateProject", "onlyAdminsSeeDashboard", "defaultBillableProjects", "isProjectPublicByDefault", "lockTimeEntries", "round", "projectFavorites", "canSeeTimeSheet", "projectPickerSpecialFilter", "forceProjects", "forceTasks", "forceTags", "forceDescription", "onlyAdminsSeeAllTimeEntries", "onlyAdminsSeePublicProjectsEntries", "trackTimeDownToSecond", "projectGroupingLabel", "adminOnlyPages", "automaticLock", "onlyAdminsCreateTag"}),
        #"Expanded memberships" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded workspaceSettings", "memberships"),
        #"Expanded memberships1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded memberships", "memberships", {"userId", "hourlyRate", "targetId", "membershipType", "membershipStatus"}, {"userId", "hourlyRate.1", "targetId", "membershipType", "membershipStatus"}),
        #"Expanded hourlyRate" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded memberships1", "hourlyRate", {"amount", "currency"}, {"amount", "currency"}),
        #"Expanded round" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded hourlyRate", "round", {"round", "minutes"}, {"round.1", "minutes"}),
        #"Expanded adminOnlyPages" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded round", "adminOnlyPages")
    in
        #"Expanded adminOnlyPages"
in 
    Query1
```

If you are not using Postman and Fiddler, I recommend it for testing the endpoints and check the responses.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately this still doesn't load the single time entries

Comment: yes it absolutely is another endpoint but I don't know how to access it. I reckon that i should go for this endpoint here: https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#tag-Report. I simply don't know how to add this to the query

Comment: You can follow the pattern in my answer. The only differences are the query parameters that you need in that endpoint, which you add like:  [Headers=[#"x-api-key"="YOUR-API-KEY"], query=[end="x", start="y", zoomLevel="z"]].
If you don't know where is the data you want, maybe try with Postman before trying with Power Query.