# How to access Clockify API through Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, clockify

I am new to Clockify and to API usage (so I apologize if I express myself not properly). My objective is to automatically load in Excel (via Power Query) the detailed report with all time entries. I have tried the below code and it works ... but for the fact that I got just the latest 50 time entries.

This because, as I understand properly, I should use this base Endpoint: "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1" (the one I use is deprecated). Is there a way to make the below work on the correct Endpoint?

```
let Source = Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/reports/{your report ID}", [https://api.clockify.me/api", #"X-Api-Key"="{your API Key}"]]), jsonResponse = Json.Document(Source), workspace = jsonResponse[workspace] in workspace
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I didn't understand what you really want, but here are some Clockify questions that might help you understand, or at least edit your question for better understanding:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006036/clockify-best-way-to-get-all-data-into-excel-or-access-using-the-rest-api/60006661#60006661

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59403580/load-clockify-data-to-power-bi/59407101#59407101